# Python multiprocessing and independence of children processes

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, children, orphan

From the python terminal, I run some command like the following, to spawn a long-running child process:

```
from multiprocessing.process import Process
Process(target=LONG_RUNNING_FUNCTION).start()
```

This command returns, and I can do other things in the python terminal, but anything printed by the child is still printed to my python terminal session.

When I exit the terminal (either with `exit` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), the exit command it hangs.  If I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during this hang, the child process is terminated.

If I kill the python terminal process manually (via the posix `kill` command), the child process is instead orphaned, and continues running with its output presumably discarded.

If I run this code with `python -c`, it waits for the child to terminate, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills both parent and child.

Which run configurations of python kill children when the parents are terminated?  In particular, if a python-mod_wsgi-apache webserver spawns child processes and then is restarted, are the children killed?

[ As an aside, what is the proper way of detaching child processes spawned from the terminal?  Is there a way more elegant than the following: [Deliberately make an orphan process in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095878/deliberately-make-an-orphan-process-in-python) ]

**Update:** python subprocesses spawned with `multiprocessing.Process` by a web server running under apache are **not** killed when apache is restarted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This isn't a matter of how you're invoking python; it's a feature of the `multiprocessing` module.  When you import that module an exit handler is added to the parent process that calls `join()` on the `Process` objects of all children created via `multiprocessing.Process` before allowing the parent to exit.  If you're going to start child processes in this fashion, there's no way, without hacking the module internals, to avoid the behavior that's giving you trouble.

If you want to start a process that's able to outlive the parent, then you'll probably be better served using `subprocess.Popen`. If the child's started that way, the parent won't attempt to join the child before exiting and will instead exit immediately, leaving an orphaned child:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> Popen(["sleep", "100"], start_new_session=True)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10d3fedd0>
>>> exit()
alp:~ $ ps -opid,ppid,command | grep sleep | grep -v grep
37979     1 sleep 100
```

Is there a particular reason you're using `multiprocessing` instead of `subprocess`?  The former isn't intended to be used to create child processes meant to outlive the parent; it's for creating child processes to do work that can be usefully parallelized across CPUs, as a way of circumventing the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). (I'm ignoring the distributed capabilities of `multiprocessing` for purposes of this discussion.) `multiprocessing` is thus normally used in those cases where, if there weren't a GIL, you would use threads. (Note, in this regard, that the `multiprocessing` module's API is modeled closely after that of the `threading` module.)

To the specific questions at the end of your post: (1) Nothing about python is responsible for killing children when the parent is terminated.  A child of the web server will only be killed if the parent kills it before exiting (or if the entire process group is killed).  (2) The method you link to looks like it's trying to replicate daemonization without knowledge of the standard idioms for doing that. There are a number of packages out there for creating daemon processes; you should use one of them instead.

Comment: subprocess is my go-to module for dispatching system calls, but using subprocess to launch background python tasks seemed inappropriate.  Have you used a good python-deamon library (such as python-deamon)?

Comment: The background/foreground distinction is specific to job control in a shell; it doesn't make sense to use those terms in application to process management in general.  In the more general context, daemonization is something that a process performs for itself, and using `subprocess.Popen` to start such a process is entirely standard.  `python-daemon` is fine; it has a cumbersome API, but it's battle tested, and the latter quality is important, since it's easy to get this sort of thing wrong.