# Running background task base on function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to ask, is there any option to make function call in another process? For example:

```py
def foo()
    while True:
        do_something...
#main function
def main()
    foo()
    some_other_actions...
    #end
```

I would like to make foo running in some other process yet allow main() to normal end and allow user to write anything else in terminal, something like:

- user run in terminal main()
- main ends (foo function still working)
- user can run in terminal anything else (without switching terminal window) yet foo function still working in some other process

I know that there are some answers like, using threading or multiprocess but after using them, program will not stop until foo() function end. Is there any option to make such a thing in Python2.7?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the multiprocessing module

Comment: As far as I used multiprocessing module, program will not exit until foo() function end, or there are some options that allow to main process end leaving foo() process alive?

Comment: voting to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095878/deliberately-make-an-orphan-process-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deliberately make an orphan process in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095878/deliberately-make-an-orphan-process-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `multiprocessing` module to do this. There are several options for how to actually implement the whole thing, probably the best would be to create a process pool and a job queue. Whenever you get some action that needs to be executed you add it to the job queue from the process running `main` and one the workers in the pool will pick it up.

The module is pretty well documented so you should find everything you need from the official python docs for `multiprocessing`.

There's a question on SO on how to launch orphaned processes in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095878/deliberately-make-an-orphan-process-in-python#13096649), but you really want to think twice if you want to do that. Are the subprocess calls *guaranteed* to end?

You could also do something crazy like use ZeroMQ as a queuing system for the job to be executed but that's probably beyond the scope of what you're looking for here. Might be an interesting read though